# I am trying to draw a flat surface plane on WEBGL

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, unity-webgl, webgl-earth

I wanted to create a floor with a table and a cube on top (mainly the floor to begin with) I have tried to run the drawFloor() function with the specified colours but no response. Any tips or advice?

I have stored the coordinates of the floor in the floorVertexPositionBuffer.

I have already specified the coordinates for the cube and indices inside a buffer.

Also, are the numbers we specify in WebGL to translate and store coordinates of shapes in buffers in screen pixel units?

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Drawing In 3D </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="glMatrix.js"></script>

<script src="webgl-debug.js"></script>


<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
  attribute vec4 aVertexColor;




  varying vec4 vColor;

  void main() {

    vColor = aVertexColor;
  }
</script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec4 vColor;

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var gl;
var canvas;
var shaderProgram;
var floorVertexPosition;
var floorVertexPositionBuffer;





function createGLContext(canvas) {
  var names = ["webgl", "experimental-webgl"];
  var context = null;
  for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    try {
      context = canvas.getContext(names[i]);
    } catch(e) {}
    if (context) {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (context) {
    context.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
    context.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
  } else {
    alert("Failed to create WebGL context!");
  }
  return context;
}

function loadShaderFromDOM(id) {
  var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!shaderScript) {
    return null;
  }
  var shaderSource = "";
  var currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;
  while (currentChild) {
    if (currentChild.nodeType == 3) { // 3 corresponds to TEXT_NODE
      shaderSource += currentChild.textContent;
    }
    currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
  }

  var shader;

  if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
    shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
    shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  } else {
    return null;
  }

  gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
  gl.compileShader(shader);

  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    return null;
  }
  return shader;
}

function setupShaders() {
  var vertexShader = loadShaderFromDOM("shader-vs");
  var fragmentShader = loadShaderFromDOM("shader-fs");

  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert("Failed to setup shaders");
  }

  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

  shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute =
gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
  shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute =
gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");




  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);
}

function pushModelViewMatrix() {
  var copyToPush = mat4.create(modelViewMatrix);
  modelViewMatrixStack.push(copyToPush);
}

function popModelViewMatrix() {
  if (modelViewMatrixStack.length == 0) {
    throw "Error popModelViewMatrix() - Stack was empty ";
  }
  modelViewMatrix = modelViewMatrixStack.pop();
}

function setupFloorBuffers() {
  floorVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floorVertexPositionBuffer);

  var floorVertexPosition = [
      // Plane in y=0
       5.0,   0.0,  5.0,  //v0
       5.0,   0.0, -5.0,  //v1
      -5.0,   0.0, -5.0,  //v2
      -5.0,   0.0,  5.0]; //v3

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(floorVertexPosition),
gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  floorVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
  floorVertexPositionBuffer.numberOfItems = 4;

  floorVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, floorVertexIndexBuffer);

  var floorVertexIndices = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new
Uint16Array(floorVertexIndices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  floorVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
  floorVertexIndexBuffer.numberOfItems = 4;
}

function setupCubeBuffers() {
  cubeVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);

  var cubeVertexPosition = [
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0, //v0
      -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, //v1
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, //v2
       1.0, -1.0,  1.0, //v3
       1.0,  1.0, -1.0, //v4
      -1.0,  1.0, -1.0, //v5
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, //v6
       1.0, -1.0, -1.0, //v7
      ];

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(cubeVertexPosition),
gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
  cubeVertexPositionBuffer.numberOfItems = 8;

  cubeVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
  var cubeVertexIndices = [
            0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,    // Front face
            4, 6, 5,    4, 7, 6,    // Back face
            1, 5, 6,  1, 6, 2, //left
  0, 3, 7,  0, 7, 4, //right
  0, 5, 1,  0, 4, 5, //top
  3, 2, 6,  3, 6, 7  //bottom
        ];

  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices),
gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  cubeVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
  cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numberOfItems = 36;
}

function setupBuffers() {
  setupFloorBuffers();
  setupCubeBuffers();
}



function uploadModelViewMatrixToShader() {
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.uniformMVMatrix, false,
modelViewMatrix);
}

function uploadProjectionMatrixToShader() {
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.uniformProjMatrix,
false, projectionMatrix);
}

function drawFloor(r,g,b,a) {
  // Disable vertex attrib array and use constant color for the floor.
  gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);
  // Set colour
  gl.vertexAttrib4f(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, r, g, b, a);

  // Draw the floor
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floorVertexPositionBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute,
floorVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize,
gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, floorVertexIndexBuffer);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, floorVertexIndexBuffer.numberOfItems,
gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}

function drawCube(r,g,b,a) {
  // Disable vertex attrib array and use constant color for the cube.
  gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);
  // Set color
  gl.vertexAttrib4f(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, r, g, b, a);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute,
cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize,
gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numberOfItems,
gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}

function drawTable(){
  // Draw table top



  // Draw table legs


}

function draw() {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);




  // Draw floor in red color
  drawFloor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  // Draw table

  // Draw box on top of the table


}

function startup() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myGLCanvas");
  gl = WebGLDebugUtils.makeDebugContext(createGLContext(canvas));
  setupShaders();
  setupBuffers();
  gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

  draw();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startup();">
  <canvas id="myGLCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should try using some 3d webgl library like https://threejs.org/examples? It's much simpler to use rather than raw webgl